# How to change an image on specific pages using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay so I learned how to remove elements on specific pages and allow them to appear on others. I thought i might be able to apply the same principle for images.

I have a banner image that I'd like to have it different on multiple pages, now instead of having to build a whole new page wrapper (i am using a CMS called Luminate) for each page, or learning their own programming language that is confusing as hell...I thought let's just use jQuery.

So what I tried to do was this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.href == "http://convio.cancer.ca/site/TR/Events/General?pg=informational&fr_id=21959&type=fr_informational&sid=10335") {
        //new banner 
        $('#bannerrmv').attr("src", "../images/content/pagebuilder/bikerunning.png");
    } else {
        //original banner   
        $('#bannerrmv').attr("src", "../images/content/pagebuilder/cancer_fighter_sweat_971_x_327103179.jpg")
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work. If i were to use `.hide()` and `.show()` it does work to hide the banner that I have.

This is the html for the banner:

```
<div class="banner-container" id="bannerrmv">
  <img src="../images/content/pagebuilder/cancer_fighter_sweat_971_x_327103179.jpg" class="banner" width="100%" alt="Image Name" />  
</div>
```

I've searched Stack and I've come across a bunch with similar questions but different scenarios.

I feel like I `.href` is incorrect but I don't know what I would change it to.

also if I wanted to make it for multiple urls all I would need to do is add `||` and then the url right?

Any suggestions would be super appreciated! thank you for your time.

Comment: where is the `bannerrmv` id in the html part? You have to define it in html before using it in javascript

Comment: OH gah its suppose to be in the img tag shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, you got that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yup. target the image: `$.('#bannerrmv img').attr("src","../images/content/pagebuilder/bikerunning.png"`)

Comment: oh wow i didn't know we could do it like that. so adding a space and then the element doesn't cause problems?

Comment: that would target *any* images inside the element named bannerrmv.

Comment: ok this is perfect because it's also replacing the mobile view images too! dope thank you so much sweaver. That saves  me a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, switching the pathname value and defining the respective url that you want to replace the old one:

```
var imageToChange = $('#img')[0];

switch(document.location.pathname){
    case '/url/first':
        imageToChange.src = 'first.jpg';
        break;
    case '/url/second':
        imageToChange.src = 'second.jpg';
        break;
    ...
}
```